# How to find the polarity of words using nltk?

Tags: nltk, review

I am doing sentiment analysis on mobile product reviews, I need to find the polarity of each extracted opinion word to positive or negative. So, i need to know if is that possible with nltk? or if any better tools are available for finding polarity of the word? please let me know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at [textblob](https://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/dev/)

You can do various things like:

- Noun phrase extraction
- Part-of-speech tagging
- Sentiment analysis
- Classification (Naive Bayes, Decision Tree)
- find polarity of sentences

  etc

[Download link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/textblob)

Comment: Thank you for replying...  I have used TextBlob for classifying using classifiers like(NaiveBayesClassifier,DecisionTreeClassifier,MaxEntClassifier) . Now i want to know weather there are any other classifiers in python-TextBlob for classification other than the classifiers which i have mentioned.

Comment: @RajeeVVenkaT http://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api_reference.html#module-textblob.classifiers